# Go program to find duplicated files in a directory (recursively)

Tags: beginner, file-system, go

This is my first Go program. I'm learning the language but it's a bit difficult to understand all the concepts so in order to practice I wrote this. It's a simple program which recursively check for duplicated files in a directory.

It uses a SHA256 hash on files in order to identify if two files are the same or not. I spawn multiple workers to handle this hashing.

Here is how it works:

- n workers (goroutine) are spawned, each of them waiting for file paths to process on the same channel, named `input` in my code.
- 1 goroutine is spawned to recursively search for files in the direvtory, and populate the `input` channel with file names.
- The main goroutine process the results as soon as they are available and add them to a map of sha256->[file, file, ...].

Finally we just display the duplicates.

Please feel to comment on anything, I really want to progress in Go, and especially "idiomatic" Go.

**EDIT: Improved my initial code with flags and error management.**

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
    "flag"
    "runtime"
    "io"
)

var dir string
var workers int

type Result struct {
    file   string
    sha256 [32]byte
}

func worker(input chan string, results chan<- *Result, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for file := range input {
        var h = sha256.New()
        var sum [32]byte
        f, err := os.Open(file)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            continue
        }
        if _, err = io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            f.Close()
            continue
        }
        f.Close()
        copy(sum[:], h.Sum(nil))
        results <- &Result{
            file:   file,
            sha256: sum,
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func search(input chan string) {
    filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        } else if info.Mode().IsRegular() {
            input <- path
        }
        return nil
    })
    close(input)
}

func main() {

    flag.StringVar(&dir, "dir", ".", "directory to search")
    flag.IntVar(&workers, "workers", runtime.NumCPU(), "number of workers")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Printf("Searching in %s using %d workers...\n", dir, workers)

    input := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan *Result)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(workers)

    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        go worker(input, results, &wg)
    }

    go search(input)
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    counter := make(map[[32]byte][]string)
    for result := range results {
        counter[result.sha256] = append(counter[result.sha256], result.file)
    }

    for sha, files := range counter {
        if len(files) > 1 {
            fmt.Printf("Found %d duplicates for %s: \n", len(files), hex.EncodeToString(sha[:]))
            for _, f := range files {
                fmt.Println("-> ", f)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hint: You may want to change the DIR for those trying elsewhere, so it doesn't panic immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and added flags to set directory and number of workers :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. declare all 'var' at once

instead of

```
var dir string
var workers int
```

you can do

```
var (
    dir string
    workers int
)
```

or even better, use local var instead of global var irectly in your `main()` function

```
dir := flag.String("dir", ".", "directory to search")
workers := flag.Int("workers", runtime.NumCPU(), "number of workers")
```

#### 2. Make sure that arguments are valid

if `worker` is <= 0, the program will panic. A little check after `flag.Parse()` could prevent this:

```
if workers <= 0 {
    fmt.Printf("workers has to be > 0, was %d", workers)
}
```

#### 3. Improve hash computing:

First, each worker only need a single instance of [hash.Hash](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash), as you can call `Reset()` on it after each file:

```
h := sha256.New()
for file := range input {
    ...
    results <- &Result{...}
    h.Reset()
}
```

Also, the hash of each file could be stored as a `string` instead of a `[32]byte` to avoid some operations:

```
results <- &Result{
    file:   file,
    sha256: fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil)),
}
```

#### 4. Always specify the channel direction when you can

From the [golang specifications](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types):

> A channel provides a mechanism for concurrently executing functions
>   to communicate by sending and receiving values of a specified element
>   type. The value of an uninitialized channel is nil.
>
> `ChannelType = ( "chan" | "chan" "<-" | "<-" "chan" ) ElementType .`
>
> The optional <- operator specifies the channel direction, send or
>   receive. If no direction is given, the channel is bidirectional. A
>   channel may be constrained only to send or only to receive by
>   conversion or assignment.

Specify the channel direction helps understand what a method is doing

---

Here is the new version of the code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

type Result struct {
    file   string
    sha256 string
}

func search(dir string, input chan<- string) {
    filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        } else if info.Mode().IsRegular() {
            input <- path
        }
        return nil
    })
    close(input)
}

func startWorker(input <-chan string, results chan<- *Result, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    h := sha256.New()
    for file := range input {
        f, err := os.Open("file.txt")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            continue
        }
        if _, err := io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
            f.Close()
            continue
        }
        f.Close()
        results <- &Result{
            file:   file,
            sha256: fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil)),
        }
        h.Reset()
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func run(dir string, workers int) (map[string][]string, error) {

    input := make(chan string)
    go search(dir, input)

    counter := make(map[string][]string)
    results := make(chan *Result)
    go func() {
        for r := range results {
            counter[r.sha256] = append(counter[r.sha256], r.file)
        }
    }()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(workers)
    for i := 0; i < workers; i++ {
        go startWorker(input, results, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)

    return counter, nil
}

func main() {

    dir := flag.String("dir", ".", "directory to search")
    workers := flag.Int("workers", runtime.NumCPU(), "number of workers")
    flag.Parse()

    if *workers <= 0 {
        fmt.Printf("workers has to be > 0, was %d \n", workers)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Searching in %s using %d workers...\n", *dir, *workers)

    counter, err := run(*dir, *workers)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed! %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for sha, files := range counter {
        if len(files) > 1 {
            fmt.Printf("Found %d duplicates for %v: \n", len(files), sha)
            for _, f := range files {
                fmt.Println("-> ", f)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Possible improvements:

Currently, if an error is thrown somewhere in the code, the program does not stop but just write the error to `os.Stderr`. It may be better to return this error and then call `os.Exit(1)`

Comment: Instead of `ioutil.ReadFile`, you could follow the [example (file) of golang.org](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#New) and use `Open` followed by `io.Copy`. Using this, the whole file does not need to be loaded in memory!

Comment: @oliverpool you're right, thanks for noticing this! I've updated the code